# "List All References" not available in context menu in VSC 1.29.1

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently upgraded to VS Code 1.29.1 on my Ubuntu virtual machine and was very excited to try out the new `List all References` preview, but I can't seem to invoke it anywhere. It isn't in the context menu, and trying `View: Show Reference Search` through the Command Palette does nothing.

[Image: No "List All References" option in the context menu when highlighting a function name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32u9k.png)

Why does the option not appear, and is there anything I can do to enable it?

My working context:
I'm working on Ubuntu 14.01 LTS and this is for a C project; all of the files in the workspace are *.c, *.h, Makefiles, and perl scripts. I have Intellisense for C/C++ enabled with the `ms-vscode.cpptools` extension. The only other Marketplace extensions I have installed are color/icon theme-related. Symbol searching, go/peek to declaration/definition, quick info, error squiggles, etc. are all working properly.

Things I've tried:

- verified that I'm actually using version 1.29.1 via the Help>About menu option (and confirmed multiline regex searching works)
- skimmed the GitHub repo for both open and closed issues and didn't find any similar issues
- searched the docs and patch notes
- tried various .c and .h files within the workspace.

I'm not familiar enough with the extension and language provider architecture to know where to go from here, and I couldn't glean any caveats from the docs about the new `List All References` feature, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `List All References` feature is based on `Find All References`, which is supposed to be implemented by the language provider. In my case, the `ms-vscode.cpptools` language provider has not implemented `Find All References`, so the `List All References` feature is unavailable.

(I realized the one thing I hadn't checked were the issues in vscode-cpptools.)

Relevant issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/15#issuecomment-438905148

I guess as a PSA, if you're on VSC1.29.1 and don't have the `List All References` option, look to your language provider.